# Are the Q a future evolution of humans?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I've been watching some of the TNG again and I didn't notice it when I was younger but Q seems to hint that the Q were once human, Is it ever confirmed ?

Comment: I think the closest that this theory may come to being address is Q at one point saying something along the lines of "we were like you once." But I doubt that any Q would ever really admit to having ever been a savage, child race.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible, and it would explain Q's fascination with humanity (rather than, say, the Klingons - I would imagine that teasing some psychotic stuck-up honour-bound Klingon captain could be every bit as fun as teasing Picard), but there is no evidence for this on-screen, or even in the expaned universe books.

Comment: I dont think they were. We can only speculate. Since they can take any form or shape they want, and theyve always been here, or then they were the first species in the universe when the big bang happened, they have only been seen as a human because they want to for some reason. Their true form or original form might never be known, unless in the future jj abrams reveals it to us in tng reboot or something.

Comment: @Thrivers and of course, even if he did reveal that in the reboot films, it wouldn't necessarily apply to the 'prime' timeline :B